# AttributeError: '_lzma.LZMADecompressor' object has no attribute 'needs input'

Tags: python, python-3.7

I encountered this error while trying to load local `JSON` data using datasets. `load_dataset` is in the let out frame. I can't think of a good idea right now. Hope someone can provide some experience and methods to solve the problem.

Code:

```py
raw_dataset = load_dataset("load_datasets.py", 
                           data_files=data_files)
```

The error message is as follows:

```
File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 450, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 731, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/forp.model.training.service/app/celery_task.py", line 104, in get_start
    acc, ps, rs, f1 = main(bert_dir, save_dir)
  File "/home/forp.model.training.service/app/Use_Test/train_model.py", line 44, in main
    raw_dataset = load_dataset("./app/Use_Test/load_datasets.py", data_files=ss)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/load.py", line 748, in load_dataset
    use_auth_token=use_auth_token,
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/builder.py", line 575, in download_and_prepare
    dl_manager=dl_manager, verify_infos=verify_infos, **download_and_prepare_kwargs
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/builder.py", line 630, in _download_and_prepare
    split_generators = self._split_generators(dl_manager, **split_generators_kwargs)
  File "/root/.cache/huggingface/modules/datasets_modules/datasets/load_datasets/0b45bc13b18eca949ecdc8adead3dd00eba61d326c70c5a7442498bbdc8b0197/load_datasets.py", line 59, in _split_generators
    data_dir = dl_manager.download_and_extract(data_path)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/utils/download_manager.py", line 291, in download_and_extract
    return self.extract(self.download(url_or_urls))
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/utils/download_manager.py", line 267, in extract
    num_proc=num_proc,
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/utils/py_utils.py", line 204, in map_nested
    _single_map_nested((function, obj, types, None, True)) for obj in tqdm(iterable, disable=disable_tqdm)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/utils/py_utils.py", line 204, in <listcomp>
    _single_map_nested((function, obj, types, None, True)) for obj in tqdm(iterable, disable=disable_tqdm)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/utils/py_utils.py", line 142, in _single_map_nested
    return function(data_struct)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/utils/file_utils.py", line 307, in cached_path
    and not tarfile.is_tarfile(output_path)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 2442, in is_tarfile
    t = open(name)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 1575, in open
    return func(name, "r", fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 1702, in xzopen
    t = cls.taropen(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 1623, in taropen
    return cls(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 1486, in __init__
    self.firstmember = self.next()
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 2289, in next
    tarinfo = self.tarinfo.fromtarfile(self)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 1094, in fromtarfile
    buf = tarfile.fileobj.read(BLOCKSIZE)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/lzma.py", line 205, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/_compression.py", line 68, in readinto
    data = self.read(len(byte_view))
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/_compression.py", line 96, in read
    if self._decompressor.needs_input:
AttributeError: '_lzma.LZMADecompressor' object has no attribute 'needs_input'
```

Comment: Bizarre.  The `lzma` documentation says the object supports `needs_input`, but it's not in the source.  In fact, the final line in your traceback is the ONLY instance of the word `needs_input` in the standard library.  Is it supposed to come from a DLL?

Answer (score -1):

The '_lzma.lzmadecompressor' is related to the pandas version, trying to lower the versions of other related modules. My problem has been solved for now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).